# Moving rows to another sheet based on a cell value script

Tags: google-apps-script

Looking to move cells based on a value in google sheets using a script. Super green to all of this, just after watching some videos on the basics & using code found on a site, trying to make this work for my spreadsheet.

```
function doneCopy() {

 var app = SpreadsheetApp;
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var sheetNameToWatch = ss.getSheetByName("Current")
 var columnNumberToWatch = 8;
 var valueToWatch = "DONE" ;
 var sheetNameToMoveTheRowTo = "OLD";

 //var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();//this has already been declared
 var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
 var range = sheet.getActiveCell();

 if (sheet.getName() == "Current" && range.getColumn() == 8 && range.getValue() == "DONE") {
   var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("OLD");
   var targetRange = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);

   sheet.getRange(range.getRow(), 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).moveTo(targetRange);
   sheet.deleteRow(range.getRow());
 }

}
```

It appears to not being working at all. Here is a link to the spreadsheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1iRMuKKhC83lot4TV2dbOfBlgdtVzSuZ0rkoWKyTOUIM/edit?usp=sharing

End Goal: When the "Status" Column is "DONE" the whole row is moved to the "OLD" sheet (adding a row on the bottom) & then deleted from the "Current" sheet

Comment: In your shared Spreadsheet, the sheet name of "OLD" becomes ``" OLD"`` which has a space at the top letter. When the script is run, ``targetSheet`` becomes ``null`` and error occurs at ``var targetRange = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);``. So please modify the sheet name of "OLD" from ``" OLD"`` to ``OLD``, and run again.

Comment: Wow. That is funny.

Comment: Fixed, Sheet corrected to "OLD" from " OLD"

Comment: Still not working.

Comment: I apologize my comment was not useful for your situation. Can you provide the detail information about ``Still not working.``? By this, it will help users think of your solution.

Comment: It was useful! The script does not work, If I select the status as done it does not copy to the "OLD" sheet or delete from the "Current" sheet.

Comment: I tried your updated Spreadsheet now. When I select a cell "H7" on "Current" sheet and run the script, the row is moved to the last row of "OLD" sheet. Is this the result you want?

Comment: Ah. My apologies, I'm still figuring this out. What i'm looking for is if any cells (in the whole status column) say done, it moves that row. Does that make sense?

also, is there a way to make this automatic, instead of having to go into the script and run it (as soon as the input is "DONE" it moves)? or possibly make a new drop down menu that has it so I can run it once and it'll effect the whole sheet?

Comment: You want to move all rows which have "Done" in the column "H" to "OLD" sheet by running the script. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Yes, and if Possible make it happen as soon as "DONE" is typed in it moves or put it in a drop down menu (so you don't have to go into the script).

Thanks, I really appreciate your help!

Comment: Thank you for replying. I cannot understand about ``put it in a drop down menu (so you don't have to go into the script)``. Can you explain about it?

Comment: Add an custom menu at the top to run the script as seen here: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/menus

Comment: You want to run the script by the custom menu. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Yes & make it's effect all rows that have column "h" as "DONE"

Comment: Thank you for replying. I proposed a modified script. Could you please confirm it? If this was not the result you want, I apologize.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You want to move all rows which have "Done" in the column "H" to "OLD" sheet by running the script.
- You want to run the script by the custom menu.

I could understand like above. If my understanding is correct, how about this modification? I think that there are several answers for your situation. So please think of this as just one of them. The flow of this modified script is as follows.

1. Retrieve values of column "H" on "Current" sheet.
2. Retrieve row indexes for moving to "OLD" sheet.
3. Move the values.
4. Delete the rows.

#### Modified script:

```
function onOpen() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu('Custom Menu')
      .addItem('doneCopy', 'doneCopy')
      .addToUi();
}

function doneCopy() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Current");
  var values = sheet.getRange(1, 8, sheet.getLastRow(), 1).getValues();
  var moveRows = values.reduce(function(ar, e, i) {
    if (e[0] == "DONE") ar.push(i + 1);
    return ar;
  }, []);
  var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("OLD");
  moveRows.forEach(function(e) {
    sheet.getRange(e, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).moveTo(targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1));
  });
  moveRows.reverse().forEach(function(e) {sheet.deleteRow(e)});
}
```

#### Note:

- `onOpen()` is run when you open the Spreadsheet. After open the Spreadsheet, please run the script from the custom menu.

#### References:

- [getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues)
- [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)
- [for​Each()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

Comment: @Kevin Ahrens Thank you for your response.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu('New Menu') {
  .addItem('Run', 'doneCopy')
  .addToUi()
}

function doneCopy() {
 var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
 var sheet=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
 var range=sheet.getActiveCell();
 if (sheet.getName()=="Current" && range.getColumn()==8 && range.getValue()=="DONE") {
   var targetSheet=ss.getSheetByName("OLD");
   var targetRange=targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);//column one
   sheet.getRange(range.getRow(), 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).moveTo(targetRange);
   sheet.deleteRow(range.getRow());
 }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Used the other answer, really appreciate the response and thanks for correcting my spelting erorrs!

Comment: Check screenshot at https://stackoverflow.com/a/66655601